# Как прилинковать нестандартную версию protobuf используя cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, google-protobuf, кросс-компиляция, линковка

Есть проект под arm который компилируется и собирается на х86ой машине (кросскомпиляция). Есть версия библиотеки protobuf собранная под arm по этой
[инструкции](https://github.com/eurotech/edc-examples/wiki/Cross-compiling-protobuf-for-ARM-architecture). В cmake файле я пытаюсь явно указать местоположение собранной под arm библиотеки через переменную Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER но похоже что cmake эта переменная вообще побоку. Что мне сделать что бы find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) нашёл ту версию protobuf которая мне нужна?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread ") #-lboost_system
project(proto_test)

# Подключаем протобуф 
set (Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER "/home/mrfieldy/prot_build/protobuf-3.5.1-arm/src")  
#set (Protobuf_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)   
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS test.proto)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} test.pb.cc ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

---

### Ответ:

В общем, как посоветовали ниже, я выбрал путь сначала выполнить find_package, а потом с помошью set переопределить пути. Долго искал на какие пути надо переопределить. Вот рабочий вариант.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread ")
project(proto_test)
# Подключаем протобуф 
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
set (PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/mrfieldy/prot_build/protobuf-3.6.0-arm/src/")
set (PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES "/home/mrfieldy/prot_build/protobuf-3.6.0-arm/src/.libs/libprotobuf.so")
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
#protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS test.proto)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} test.pb.cc ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Раз уж вы не используйте сборку / установку protobuf посредством cmake, то и надеяться на find_package не зачем. Указывайте параметры компиляции и линковки явно.

Comment: Попробуйте выставить `Protobuf_ROOT` в путь, который является корнем для директории `lib`.

Comment: @ixSci там нет директории lib(есть только для руби). Я пробовал выставить Protobuf_ROOT различные директории по аналогии c boost_ROOT но CMake'у вообще побоку на все эти переменные.

Comment: у меня нет protobuf, так что я не знаю, что там и где лежит. Попробуйте выставить этот путь туда, где лежат библиотеки `protobuf` и `protoc`. И не забудьте удалить кэш CMake, перед тем, как проверять работу.

Comment: Добавьте структуру директорий в вопрос (где лежат библиотеки и include), чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: ixSci всё что раскидывается при make install лежит в src. В том числе папка google откуда всё линкуется. Но если прописывать путь до неё без find_package то не чего не работает -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поискал по переменной `Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER` и нашел вот что:

[FindProtobuf](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindProtobuf.html)

К сожалению мой английский `sehr schlecht`, но, насколько я понял у вас версия `cmake` слишком низкая (документация там начинается с 3.02), а сама переменная касается лишь определенного случая, касающегося `Visual Studio` и, что-то мне подсказывает, это не то, что вы используете.

Посоветую написать `Find`-файл самому - это довольно [просто](https://procplusplus.blogspot.com/2011/06/cmake-3.html)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

Comment: Может возникнуть проблема с `find_library` и `find_path` - вместо них можно просто установить нужную информацию в переменный посредствам `set` (так я сделал, так как я так и не разобрался как работают эти две функции).

Comment: Какие значения этих переменных вы установили относительно папки src?

Comment: я прописывал абсолютные пути от корня

Comment: @mrFieldy вот пример моего `find` для pdcurses для кросскомпиляции: include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
if(CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR AND CURSES_LIBRARIES)
    set(PDCurses_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
endif(CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR AND CURSES_LIBRARIES)
set(CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include)
set(CURSES_LIBRARIES /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libpdcurses.a)
find_package_handle_standard_args(PDCurses DEFAULT_MSG CURSES_LIBRARIES CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR)
mark_as_advanced(CURSES_LIBRARIES)

Comment: спасибо. Сейчас вывел значения переменных которые задаёт команда `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` через `message(STATUS "[${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}][${PROTO_SRCS}][${PROTO_HDRS}]") `но не увидел для себя не чего нового. Видать эта команда делает ещё что-то.

Answer (score 2):

У нас похожая ситуация, только QtCreator.
Может поможет.
Это переменные конфигурации CMake

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это toolchain (если собирать не в QtCreator, а в консоли):

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(buildrootdir /home/vegorov/Build-Root/04.06.2018/BR-opo)
set(buildtriplet arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${buildrootdir}/output/host/${buildtriplet}/sysroot)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX ${buildroot}/output/spo-stage)

set(tools ${buildrootdir}/output/host/)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/${buildtriplet}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/${buildtriplet}-g++)
set(PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE "${tools}bin/protoc")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${buildrootdir}/output/host/${buildtriplet}/sysroot/usr/lib/cmake)
set(OE_QMAKE_PATH_EXTERNAL_HOST_BINS ${tools}/bin/)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(COMPILER_FLAGS "--sysroot=${CMAKE_SYSROOT} -O2 -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${COMPILER_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${COMPILER_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
#set(envpath $ENV{PATH})
#set(ENV{PATH} "${tools}bin:${envpath}" )
#message(STATUS ":${tools}bin:${envpath}")
```

Comment: Похоже, вы тут устанавливаете путь к бинарику компилятора protobuf

Comment: да, это путь к бинарнику который компилирует pb.cc файлы. Подключения самой библиотеки я тут не вижу. Я тоже использую QtCreator но только без их фреймворка.

Comment: а я и не писал что здесь решается ваша проблема с библиотекой, 
`Andrej Levkovitch` как мне кажется дал верный ответ. Но у меня возникали проблемы с поиском protobufc при сборке под arm, и я потратил приличное количество времени на настройку этого дела в QtCreator, и решил что на всякий случай можно оставить это здесь, может быть потом кому-нибудь пригодится.

Comment: @vegorov спасибо.

Comment: @mrFieldy ну и я кстати щас пошукал по нашему Sysroot - не нашёл конфигов для protobuf, тем не менее `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` у нас как-то работает, библиотеки protobuf просто лежат в `sysroot/usr/lib/` + указан protobufc. Каких-то других специальных настроек для Protobuf я не нашёл (у нас в проекте), и FindProtobuf.cmake у нас тоже нет

Comment: @vegorov она у меня тоже от туда работает если сделать make install из сборки под arm =) Но после этого как вы понимаете вы уже даже protoc не запустите. Если честно, до того как я написал сюда,  у меня была мысль добавить в сборочный скрипт выполнение make install нужной версии каждый раз при компиляции =). Но это слишком бредово.