# Как в cmake производит поиск библиотек в Windows?

Tags: c++, cmake, кроссплатформенность, google-protobuf

Пишу небольшой кроссплатформенный проект на qt5 + cmake с использованием protobuf. На linux всё собирается замечательно но на windows cmake не может выполнит команду `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)`. Протобуф устанавливал как указано [тут](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md#c-installation---windows). В итоге у меня есть папка с библиотекой но как мне заставить Cmake находить эту папку как источник библиотеки? Пробовал заносить пути в переменные среды под различными именами но это не помогает.

CMake скрипт:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(untitled3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread")

# Подключаем протобуф.
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}

    ...

    )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets Core Network)
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь выполнить `find_package` ну а соответствующий файл у вас есть? Должно быть что-то вроде `FindProtobuf.cmake`.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Нет, я про это не чего не знаю. Как вообще cmake производит поиск? Почему на linux он находит protobuf а на windows нет? Если что, на текущий момент вопрос не решён.

Comment: cmake как раз таки, производит поиск с помощью файлов FindSomename.cmake. Скорее всего у вас просто нет нужного файла - cmake вам прямо так и должен был написать, что нету файла.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch угу, вы правы. Он пишет C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.12\Modules\FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137: error: Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR) C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:543 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package). Сейчас попробуй отредактировать этот файл =)

Comment: Попробовал вставить соответствующие сеты в разных местах этого макроса но это не помогло. Сейчас разбираюсь что там написано, может что нарою.

Comment: судя по всему у вас неправильные пути стоят... Как вы устанавливали ваш Protobuf?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ссылка в вопросе. Но если вы знаете другой вариант, можете мне рассказать. Я попробую.

Comment: а каким компилятором собираете?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch MinGW 6.3. Кстати там у меня в макросе флаг стоит -std=c++17. Я поменял его на -std=c++14 т.к. эта версия MinGW 17тый не поддерживает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну, например можно так

```
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Windows)

...........

include_directories ("d:/library/include")
link_directories( "d:/library/lib") 

...........

elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Linux)

 ..................

endif()
```

Comment: Я пробовал так `#find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
    set (PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/MainProjects/vcpkg/packages/protobuf_x86-windows/include/")
    set (PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES "C:/MainProjects/vcpkg/packages/protobuf_x86-windows/lib/")
    include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` но cmake не смог это собрать.

Comment: я хотел сказать что без find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) во время компиляции макросы которые стоят в исходном коде протобуфа не дают откомпилировать код (мол сбой на этапе проверки версии протобуфа и вообще библиотека подключена как то неправильно). Так происходит на обоих платформах.

Comment: не смог собрать, как то расплывчато. Диагностика какая была?

Comment: Ошибка компиляции на всех макросах GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION. Эти макросы стоят в файлах которые выдаёт метакомпилятор протобуфа. Ошибка компиляции: error: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int, int, char const*)'. На всякий случай уточню что версия протобуфа на обоих системах 3.6.1.

Comment: не знаю, может это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043184/cmake-doesnt-work-with-google-protobuf. Есть подозрение на cmake

Comment: Я решал подобную [проблему 2 месяца назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850955/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e-protobuf-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-cmake). т.е настраивал компиляцию potobuf на linux под arm (для этого нужно было использовать вариант скомпилированный специально под arm). Тогда я пришёл к выводу что вызов find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) обязателен. Надо заставить его...

Comment: Надо просто заставить работать эту команду на windows.